# Why is .bind() used in this example?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
var TwitterListModel = function (lists, selectedList) {
    // [...]

    this.addUser = function () {
        if (this.userNameToAdd() && this.userNameToAddIsValid()) {
            this.editingList.userNames.push(this.userNameToAdd());
            this.userNameToAdd("");
        }
    };

    this.removeUser = function (userName) {
        this.editingList.userNames.remove(userName)
    }.bind(this);

    // [...]
}
```

I've found this code in [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/twitter.html) from Knockout JS examples. They are declared inside of an object. I'd like to understand why the first function doesn't use `.bind(this)` and the second does.

When and why is it necessary to use `.bind(this)`? It looks like if I use it or not makes no difference: the meaning of `this` is always referred to the object in which the method is declared (and not the anonymous function in which it is found). Am I right?

Both these methods access `this.editingList` and they're referring to the same variable in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeUser` is bound to the context of the row in the array.

`$root` points out the parent, but when the click handler is called the `this` context will be pointing to the item clicked. This is by design by the KO team.

You can also solve it like this

```
<button data-bind='click: $root.removeUser.bind($parent)'>Remove</button>
```

This will also work with protoype function declaration

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rhQLj/) they provide for this example...

If you try to remove the `.bind(this)` you will see that `this` (add a `console.log(this)` in this method) then refers to the username. This is due to the fact that the `removeUser` function is bind on the button in the loop over the usernames (`<ul data-bind='foreach: userNames'>`).

For the other binding, it is attached to the form and then goes with the whole model.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like removeUser is intended to use in a callback, and in the callback `this` won't refer to the TwitterListModel, so they explicitly assign TwitterListModel as `this` to the function